# Why Laravel 5.8 dispatch with database driver works like sync?

Tags: php, laravel, php-5.6, laravel-5.8, laravel-queue

I changed the queue driver in `.env` and `config/queue.php` from `sync` to `database`. Then I ran `php artisan cache:clear`.

I created a new job with the command `php artisan make:job SendEmailJob`

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

use App\Mail\SendEmailMailable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class SendEmailJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Mail::to('hello@example.com')->send(new SendEmailMailable());
    }
}
```

Then I wrote this route in `routes\web.php`

```
use App\Jobs\SendEmailJob;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher;

Route::get('sendEmail', function(){
    $job = (new SendEmailJob())->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(5));
    dispatch($job);
    return 'Email is sent properly';
});
```

I stopped `php artisan serve`, the started again.

I chacked the result of `env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'database');`, it returns `database`.

I ran `php artisan queue:work`, but there is no output.
The email sent to SMTP server like `sync` driver.

Is there anything I missed?

My PHP version is **5.6**.

Comment: Laravel 5.8 [requires](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/laravel) PHP 7.1.3. Given you received "no output" when you visited the `sendEmail` route, I'd expect you to have received a fatal error somewhere inside `dispatch`. Recommend you check your logs.

Comment: @bishop I checked inside the file `storage/logs/laravel.log`. There is no new log.

Comment: Have you tried with Artisan::queue instead of dispatch

Comment: errors on the queues doesn't show up on the `storage/logs/laravel.log` as the `php artisan queue:work` creates a mirror instance of your project. Try setting up a [Failed Jobs Handler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs). Another great resource to see is [How Queue Workers Work](https://divinglaravel.com/queue-workers-how-they-work?fbclid=IwAR0HLW30Nt3DepYK7gwiUC5gycLIE33qhq40cnT2go3gdZSz4jVQsonfYM4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a PHP version problem. I Upgraded PHP to version 7.1 and problem solved.

Comment: Thanks for adding a description of how you fixed it - people too often do not do so!